# Emulate Optional/Nullable in C as a pointer allocated for an object which is present?

Tags: c, nullable

I have seen some code which emulated Optional/Nullable values in C as pointers allocated only in case when an object exists. So it looks like this:

```
typedef struct X_str {
  int *field_a;
} X;

void do_initialization(X* obj) {
  obj->field_a = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *(obj->field_a) = // assign some value here
}

void do_processing_elsewhere(X* obj) {
   if (obj->field_a == NULL) {
      // Do no processing related to field_a
   } else {
      // Do some processing related to field_a
   }
}
```

IMHO this is at least bizarre way to do such a thing, because the memory allocator is would fragment more for no particular reason. Is there a proper way to do Nullable-like behavior (if you have no illegible object comparison to which could yield null implicitly)? Fields are public, so giving accessor functions (which could update a bit presence flag) would not give much unless you can impose that people would use them. Language is C and not C++ (where other solutions exist).